# How to change the default "Extra notes" in invoices?

Tags: gnucash

It always says "Thank you for your patronage!", which I can manually edit every time I create an invoice, but how can I change it permanently?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I googled around and found a [gnucash FAQ](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/FAQ).

> **Q: How do I customise the default invoice report options so my printable invoices always load with the options I want?**
>
> A: The easy workaround is to change the options as you like and then leave the report open in a tab, simply changing the invoice number as necessary.
>
> Alternatively, you can preset the default options by editing invoice.scm

The trick is finding that file. On a Windows system where I installed gnucash, it's in the following directory:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\gnucash\share\gnucash\scm\gnucash\report

Here's what worked for me:

1. Before starting, make a copy of the invoice.scm file and keep it somewhere safe. I didn't actually do this step, but I've noted it here as a precaution.
2. If your system doesn't let you make changes directly to the 'proper' invoice.scm file *in situ*, make a working copy of the invoice.scm file and put it anywhere you like.
3. Open the working copy with any editor (Wordpad, Notepad, etc).
4. Do a search for the word "patronage". This should lead you to the phrase that you want to edit. Make sure it's the only one in the file.
5. Edit the phrase to whatever you like, then save it. I added "very much" as a test.
6. Copy the file back to its original directory.

Here's the result when I then tried to print an invoice:

[image: Edited version]

(Note the added extra words: "very much".)

The FAQ notes that this is just for the "Printable Invoice". There's also something called a "Fancy Invoice". To change that, edit the file "fancy-invoice.scm".

If you make a mistake, copy the file from step 1 into the original location and try again. I haven't checked, but because this is done at the (gnucash) system level rather than on the company's data file, it probably controls the default message printed on any invoice on any company file you print from that machine.